# Узнать удалённую/добавленную роль пользователю discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, асинхронность

Я делаю лог-бота который выводит все логи.

Как узнать когда пользователю дали роль, и когда пользователю убрали роль?

Есть-ли по типу `on_member_role_create` или `on_member_role_remove`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, что есть функция [on_member_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update), которая получает всё о изменениях.